# Price Filter using Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have to add a price filter in my web page using Bootstrap that works as jquery slides do , See attached image for  detailed idea about it

[image]

User can  select the value and that will be set in dollors , i  am not asking for code to be pasted here ,but i wanted to ask about  is there any component in bootstrap that can be added or i should go for jquery ? if any component existis please mention it and i will go through its docs .. Thank u

Comment: have you checked this? http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-slider/

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182266/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Comment: Maybe this link could help you http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-slider/

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this: http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-slider/  ??? It works pretty much fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

There is no component that comes with Bootstrap per se, but take a look at **[this Bootstrap Slider script](http://seiyria.github.io/bootstrap-slider/)** which has been designed to be relatively plug-and-play within the Bootstrap framework and looks to offer the type of functionality you're after.

The second example is effectively exactly what you've noted, a price filter.

That said, as with the jQueryUI Slider you've illustrated it is a separate script, though likely a lighter one.

Answer (score 0):

i have used this third party tool: http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-slider/

I can highly recommend it.